# Pros and Cons of placing a method as static in the class or as private function outside of class when it doesn't utilize this?

Tags: coding-standards, typescript

I use TypeScript. When I write the below code ESlint throws this error: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this

```
export class {
  constructor() {
    const result = doCalculations()
    ...
  }

  doCalculations(): number {
    ...
  }
}
```

So I have 2 options.

1. Make the function static.
2. Move the function out of the class increasing its scope to the whole file. But since the whole file only has 1 small class this method makes sense.

```
export class {
  constructor() {
    const result = doCalculations()
    ...
  }
}

doCalculations(): number {
  ...
}
```

So I'm curious is there something that I don't see? Which method is superior and why?

Comment: Is your `doCalculations()` method just a private helper, or is it intended to be called by users of instances of the class?

Answer (score 1):

Neither one is superior. You just have to answer this questions:

- Is `doCalculations()` (not its real name) cohesive with the class purpose.
- Does `doCalculations()` need to access the object state? By the fact that it has no parameters it looks like it does, otherwise how will it do calculations and on what
- Does `doCalculations()` represent an algorithm that would be helpful to others? Again, if so it will need to receive parameters.

So I'd say that given the fact that doCalculations() receives no parameters, it access the class state, so it'd be better kept non-static.